# How to extract value from "dictionary table" in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to map two tables (ManyToOne connection) to one object in Java. One is primary CatalogObject table, the second is just a dictionary of possible types of objects. In Java I want to just have the String of type instead of mapping to a new object.
When I want to search for all objects in the class (f.e. "database") i have to first find an Id of type "database" and then find all CatalogObjects with this Id specified. Which looks a bit tedious.

```
CatalogObject Table:
    ID, Name, Parent_ID (FK), TYPE_ID (FK)

Type Table: 
    ID, Type.
```

I've created a mapping with CatalogObject and CatalogObjectType classes, but CatalogObjectType class holds only single String right now.

```
public class CatalogObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    CatalogObject parent;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    CatalogObjectType type;
}

public class CatalogObjectType implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

I want to replace CatalogObjectType with just a String value of the associated type. How to configure it for Hibernate/JPA? Can it be done?

What I want is:

```
public class CatalogObject implements Serializable {
    ...
    String name;

    @SomeAnnotation(name = "type_id")
    String type;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. One Entity class can only hold information from at most one table (but you can split a table to multiple entity classes). Just create a getter that returns the string value of the type?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can map an entity to 2 database tables in 2 simple steps:

1. You need to annotate your entity with JPA’s `@Table` and `@SecondaryTable` annotations and provide the names of the first and second table as the value of the name parameters.
2. You need to annotate each attribute which you want to map to the secondary table with a `@Column` annotation and set the name of the secondary table as the value of the table attribute.

The `@Table` annotation defines the primary table to which the entity attributes get mapped by default.
The `@SecondaryTable` annotation specifies the second database table to which the entity gets mapped.

That’s all you need to do to map the 2 database tables to the one entity.

You can check [this link](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/) for a detailed explanation with a sample.

Comment: From what I read, `@SecondaryTable` works with OneToOne associations, and here I have ManyToOne. I can have many objects with "database" type.